# Toolbar when extending Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I need to extend Activity and not ActionBarActivity or AppCompatActivity in order to use a third party library.

In all the app I've been using AppCompatActivity in order to easily add a Toolbar in it, but apparently I cannot do the same if I extend Activity. I'd be also happy just to have an ActionBar: it's not the same, but it's better than nothing. Still, I don't know how to do it :-/

Do you have any advice for me? I know it's a silly question probably but I just don't know how to make this work...

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` extends `Activity`, so your third party library should work with it. What issue are you facing?

Comment: I need to extend OPActivity, provided by the app, in order to use some methods. OPActivity extends Activity, not ActionBarActivity, and I cannot extend multiple classes in Java :-/

Comment: The library comes in a Jar, obviously, so I can't change that "extends Activity" in a more proper "extends ActionBarActivity" ;-)

Comment: The library you are using is probably outdated. You should ask them to provide a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all check the library you are using. It can be outdated.

With the new 22.1+ appcompat you can use the [AppCompatDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html) to extend AppCompat's support to any Activity.

You can check this official link to [AppCompatPreferenceActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java), where you can find an example of this technique.

You have :

- to add the `Toolbar` to your `Activity`:

Something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

- to use a `AppCompat Theme` without ActionBar.

something like this:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myColor</item>
        ....
    </style>
```

- Add `AppCompatDelegate` to your `Activity`

Something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AppCompatCallback {

      private AppCompatDelegate delegate;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //create the delegate        
            delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);

            //call the onCreate() of the AppCompatDelegate
            delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //use the delegate to inflate the layout
            delegate.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //add the Toolbar
            Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
            delegate.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

   //.....
}
```

Check the official example to wrap other methods of your Activity to have a full compatibility with AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Gabriele, I think I love you :-) Thank you so much!